# System.Text.Json Custom JsonConverter Write() never called

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0, system.text.json, json-serialization

I have a .NET 6 solution for which I'm trying to override the default format of `DateTimeOffset`'s when calling `JsonObject.ToJsonString()`. This is all using the native `System.Text.Json` libraries.

I've added a custom `DateTimeOffsetConverter`:

```
public class DateTimeOffsetConverter : JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset>
{
    private readonly string _format;

    public DateTimeOffsetConverter(string format)
    {
        _format = format;
    }

    public override DateTimeOffset Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Debug.Assert(typeToConvert == typeof(DateTimeOffset));
        return DateTimeOffset.Parse(reader.GetString());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTimeOffset value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString(_format));
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return (typeToConvert == typeof(DateTimeOffset));
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it, the code is never hit beyond the constructor being called.

What am I missing that's preventing the `JsonConverter` being called?

Here's my code which tries to make use of the functionality:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("New Zealand Standard Time")]
[InlineData("India Standard Time")]
[InlineData("Central Brazilian Standard Time")]
[InlineData("W. Australia Standard Time")]
public void DateTimeOffsetIsSerializedCorrectlyTest(string timeZoneId)
{
    const string DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz";
    var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
    var dateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(DateTimeOffset.Now.DateTime, timeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset);

    var json = new JsonObject
    {
        { "value", dateTimeOffset }
    };

    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        Converters = { new DateTimeOffsetConverter(DateTimeFormat) }
    };
    string jsonString = json.ToJsonString(options);

    Assert.Contains(jsonString, dateTimeOffset.ToString(DateTimeFormat));
}
```

There's a number of closely related question already posted, who's solutions I've experimented with, but none seem to address my precise scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the converter is applied at the time the `DateTimeOffset` is **converted to a `JsonNode`** rather than when the `JsonNode` is **formatted to a string**.  Thus you may generate the required JSON by [explicitly serializing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serializetonode) your `DateTimeOffset` rather than relying on [implicit conversion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.op_implicit?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode-op-implicit(system-datetimeoffset)-system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode):

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new DateTimeOffsetConverter(DateTimeFormat) }
};

var json = new JsonObject
{
    { "value", JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(dateTimeOffset, options) }
};
```

This results in `{"value":"2022-11-27T15:10:23.570\u002B12:00"}`.  Note that the `+` is escaped.  If your require it not to be escaped so that your `Assert.Contains(jsonString, dateTimeOffset.ToString(DateTimeFormat));` passes successfully, use [`UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.javascriptencoder.unsaferelaxedjsonescaping):

```
var formattingOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping,
    // Other formatting options as required, e.g.
    //WriteIndented = true, // This option also seems to be applied when the JsonNode is formatted to a string, rather than when it is constructed
};

string jsonString = json.ToJsonString(formattingOptions);
```

Which results in `{"value":"2022-11-27T15:17:44.142+12:00"}`.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uloxyO).

Notes:

- The documentation page [How to use a JSON document, Utf8JsonReader, and Utf8JsonWriter in System.Text.Json: `JsonNode` with `JsonSerializerOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0#jsonnode-with-jsonserializeroptions) states:

  > You can use `JsonSerializer` to serialize and deserialize an instance of `JsonNode`. However, if you use an overload that takes `JsonSerializerOptions`, the options instance is only used to get custom converters. Other features of the options instance are not used. ...

  This statement seems to be incorrect; your `DateTimeOffsetConverter` is not picked up even if you serialize your `JsonNode` hierarchy with `JsonSerializer.Serialize(json, options)`.

  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rrGNjf).
- I can't find any documentation listing the options applied during `JsonNode` construction vs `JsonNode` string formatting. The docs do show that [`WriteIndented` is applied during string formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0#create-a-jsonnode-dom-with-object-initializers-and-make-changes).  Some experimentation shows that, in addition, [`Encoder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.encoder) and (surprisingly) [`NumberHandling`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.numberhandling) are applied during string formatting.

  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O9sfP2).
- Some debugging shows why your `DateTimeOffsetConverter` is not applied during string formatting.  The [`DateTimeOffset` to `JsonNode` implicit conversion operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.op_implicit?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode-op-implicit(system-datetimeoffset)-system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode):

  ```
  JsonNode node = dateTimeOffset;
  ```

  Returns an object of type [`JsonValueTrimmable<DateTimeOffset>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.11/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Nodes/JsonValueTrimmable.cs).  This type includes its own internal converter:

  ```
  internal sealed partial class JsonValueTrimmable<TValue> : JsonValue<TValue>
  {
      private readonly JsonTypeInfo<TValue>? _jsonTypeInfo;
      private readonly JsonConverter<TValue>? _converter;
  ```

  If we access the value of `_converter` with reflection, we find it is initialized to the system converter [`DateTimeOffsetConverter`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.11/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Value/DateTimeOffsetConverter.cs):

  ```
  var fi = node.GetType().GetField("_converter", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
  Console.WriteLine("JsonValueTrimmable<T>._converter = {0}", fi.GetValue(node)); // Prints System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.DateTimeOffsetConverter
  ```

  This system converter ignores the incoming options and simply calls [`Utf8JsonWriter.WriteStringValue(DateTimeOffset);`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.11/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Value/DateTimeOffsetConverter.cs#L15).

  Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SlQd7E).

Comment: Thank you for that incredibly detailed explanation, it's very much appreciated :)